# How does one monitor the monitoring tools of a cluster?

Tags: devops, kubernetes

We have a DB Service (Apache Druid) running along with prometheus,druid-exporter and Grafana deployments all being managed in the same namespace using k8s. We often see our prometheus or Grafana deplyments go down, and we need to set up alerting for the same. But when I look up k8s observability I see that it is again setting up a prometheus deployment. Question : When you're managing the observability of the system as well,How does one monitor the monitoring tools of a cluster? If I set up a prometheus for observing something, how do I observe and monitor my prometheus set up itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR - Get someone else to do it.

We should constantly strive to improve our monitoring - ideally adding extra logic to automatically correct issues we have seen in the past. As part of that we can do several things such as:

- We can setup two top level monitoring systems, that each monitor the other in addition to other parts of the infrastructure.
- We can create "information radiators" - put monitors in the office that show a dashboard of system health, along with the timestamp of the last update.
- Send a daily all clear message to various channels (Slack, email, etc).

However the simplest solution is simply to pay someone else to make it their problem, there are plenty of "Monitoring as a service" offerings. Simply setup one of those to monitor your top level monitoring solutions (and maybe a couple of other basic checks on other infrastructure) if you only have a few checks the cost should be minimal and its now someone else's problem to monitor the paid monitoring system. **

** - The MaaS offering will likely have outages once in a while, but unless that corresponds with your outage (which may happen if you are on the same cloud provider) it is not a major issue - a quick check of your own monitoring will reveal that everything you operate is running okay.